# Using intersect/clip for polyline to polyline features resulting in Warning 000117 ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, length, intersect, warning-000117

[image]I am trying to measure the length of a polyline from its origin to its intersection with another polyline. The application is to find out the distance from a meteorological station to the coastline. I created polylines with origin in the met station outwards every 30 degrees. When I use clip/intersect I get 'Warning 000117: Warning empty output generated'. I have tried the online help for related topics and still have not solved it (exporting to a shp, to a new gdb, re-starting ArcMap, creating a new project, resetting extents, checking al layers have same coordinates).

Files I am trying to use: [ArcMapFolder](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=14paLxlLnTMGhzTB35pRjrWd0WQkKNLiK)

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=14paLxlLnTMGhzTB35pRjrWd0WQkKNLiK

I have tried also the solutions suggested in [Intersect (analysis) of polygons generating empty output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77215/intersect-analysis-of-polygons-generating-empty-output)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your data? Is it all in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Hi BERA here is the link: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9kOtN_Y530-YzNGMThENnNWWWFLQmFUN1B5UnN4Vy1pUnlR/view?usp=drivesdk

I have checked that all is in the same coordinate system.

Comment: Unless you actually want the "30 degrees distance" you could just create Points at the location of the weather stations and then use Near tool or Genereate near table to get distance from the stations to the coast line and also the direction.

Comment: Yes, the 30 degree distance to the coast for each station is the reason for this project.

Comment: I would try by iterating over each line and calculate distance. Either with modelbuilder and Iterate Feature Selection or with a python script.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion BERA. However, I was able to solve it in a different way. What I did was to transform the state boundary polyline into a polygon and then applied the clip tool, this produced a successful run.

Answer (score 1):

Often when empty output is generated during a clip or intersect operation, there is a selection on features outside of the area of interest.

Deselect all features then run the command again.

Comment: Hi Fezter, I did deselect all features an tried clip/intersect again, but it did not work. I also tried to reduce the size of the polylines and only use one meteorological station, to see if the large extents or amount of data was causing trouble and still did not get a successful run.